# how to use calaba.sh or Frank with Corona SDK app

Tags: testing, coronasdk, calabash, frank

I'd like to use either [Calaba.sh](http://calaba.sh/) or [Frank](http://www.testingwithfrank.com/) to automate the tests on my Corona SDK app on iOS.

Both tools, implies that you bundle a provided framework during the build and rely on typical XCode project organisation. I've looked into [setting up](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#setting-up-xcode-project) with Calaba.sh and [there](http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/06/24/writing-your-first-frank-test/) for frank.

But I don't know how to wire this in a Corona SDK project, even if it's possible at all.

Is there a way I can use either Calaba.sh or Frank to test a Corona SDK app ?

Comment: Frank will not work for Corona SDK, and Imagine that calabash might not work either. Frank only works when your app uses UIKit for your user interface, and I believe calabash does too. Corona SDK does not use UIKit, but rather does its own drawing using OpenGL. Instead of trying to fit a general-purpose iOS testing framework in your project, you probably want to check with the Corona SDK community to see what they use for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Frank and Calabash both need to be integrated via xcode. I would take a look at http://fperrad.github.io/lua-TestMore/ instead.